# what is the use of ... in c++

Tags: c++, operators

I tried googling `...` but as expected, google ignored it.

I have this code :

```
try {

// some code
}

catch( ... ) {
// catch logic

}
```

I'm guessing that `...` means any kind of exceptions, am I right ? 
any other usages for this ?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: @OldProgrammer any other usages for it ?

Comment: Yep. [Pokemon Exception Handling.](http://www.dodgycoder.net/2011/11/yoda-conditions-pokemon-exception.html)

Comment: You are correct. There is another usage in the context of function prototypes, which means the caller can pass as many arguments as he wants. Eg `void format(char* formatString, ...);` But make no mistake, this one is considered a C legacy rather than proper C++.

Comment: MSVC++ used this syntax to catch also the Operating Systems exceptions, what they called _SEH_ (Structured Exception Handling). BTW, this use is quite controversial.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am aware of three use cases:

- Variable number of arguments like 'printf(const char* fmt, ...)'
- A catch anything as 'catch(...)'
- A variadic template like 'template < typename ...T >' and unpacking 'T ...' (c++11)

And another one, which I missed, is preprocessing: variadic macros

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are correct, `catch(...)` means to catch all the exceptions. However it is a good practice to catch exceptions by const reference. Like

```
catch(std::exception const & ex) 
{ 
//code here
}
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6dekhbbc.aspx) remarks section:

> **Remarks:-**
>
> The code after the try clause is the guarded section of code. The
>   throw expression throws (raises) an exception. The code block after
>   the catch clause is the exception handler, and catches (handles) the
>   exception thrown by the throw expression if the type in the throw and
>   catch expressions are compatible. For a list of rules that govern
>   type-matching in catch blocks, see **_**. If the catch statement
>   specifies an ellipsis (...) rather than a type, the catch block
>   handles any type of exception, including C exceptions and system- or
>   application-generated exceptions such as memory protection, divide by
>   zero, and floating-point violations. Because catch blocks are tried in
>   program order, such a handler must be the last handler for its try
>   block. **Use catch (…) with caution; typically such a catch block is
>   used to log errors and perform any special cleanup prior to stopping
>   program execution. Do not allow a program to continue unless the catch block knows how to >handle the specific exception that is caught.**

```
try {
   throw CSomeOtherException();
}
catch(...) {  // Catch all exceptions – dangerous!!!
   // Respond (perhaps only partially) to exception
   throw;       // Pass exception to some other handler
}
```

> any other usages for this ?

One which I have seen is the usage in variable number of arguments like `'printf(const char* x, ...)'`